# Making a statistic in bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file containing about 1000 lines that are pretty much like this:

```
0,23423423,7ds5dsfdf,2008-08-03,19:00:01,101,hJ890
1,54645645,f9g8f9gd7,2008-08-03,19:00:20,113,Lg78s
1,54645645,f9g8f9gd7,2008-08-03,19:00:09,108,Lg78s
0,54645645,f9g8f9gd7,2008-08-03,19:00:01,130,dsf98
1,54645645,f9g8f9gd7,2008-08-03,19:00:20,105,Lg78s
```

The column after the time represents a number of seconds. How can I make a statistic based on the number of seconds for each date in the file, starting from the smallest one to the largest?
For example, I should get something like:

```
The date Sun Aug  3 19:00:01 EEST 2008 has 231 seconds
The date Sun Aug  3 19:00:09 EEST 2008 has 108 seconds
The date Sun Aug  3 19:00:20 EEST 2008 has 218 seconds
```

I tried something like this:

```
while read line
do
    date=awk -F "," '{print $4","$5}'
    var=grep "$date"
done
```

After I find an instance of the certain date, how can I select the number of seconds coresponding to it?

Thanks!

Comment: Your output doesn't seem to match your input? You want the output sorted by timestamp?

Comment: I just need a variable containing the sum of the seconds for a certain date, and then I can just add a command like "date -d "$date" ". The problem is I don't know how to add the number of seconds to each date.

Comment: What I am saying is that the conversion of the date format for the output is not the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk -F, '{cmd="date -d \"" $4 " " $5 "\""; cmd | getline dt; close(cmd); a[dt] += $6}
END{for (i in a) print i " has " a[i] " seconds"}' file

Sun Aug  3 19:00:09 EDT 2008 has 108 seconds
Sun Aug  3 19:00:20 EDT 2008 has 218 seconds
Sun Aug  3 19:00:01 EDT 2008 has 231 seconds
```

This `awk` command
- uses comma as input field separator.
- constructs a date string uses column 4th and 5th columns.
- uses an associative array with key as date and value as sum of seconds value

**Reference:** [Effective AWK Programming](https://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf)

If you want dates to be sorted then use `awk + sort + cut` as this one:

```
awk -F, '{s=$4 " " $5; cmd="date -d \"" s "\""; cmd | getline dt; close(cmd);
a[dt] += $6; b[dt]=s} END{for (i in a) print b[i] ";" i " has " a[i] " seconds"}' file |
sort -t ';' -k1,2 |
cut -d ';' -f2-

Sun Aug  3 19:00:01 EDT 2008 has 231 seconds
Sun Aug  3 19:00:09 EDT 2008 has 108 seconds
Sun Aug  3 19:00:20 EDT 2008 has 218 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am new to bash and it would mean a lot if you could also explain a bit what you did. But it works, so thank you!

Comment: I will come back to my desk in 30 min and then I will add explanation in my answer.

Comment: @anubhava, thanks a TON sir for nice answer. I too tried in mktime and srftime, but somewhere messed up, could you please help me if you have some time to fix it, will be grateful to you.

Comment: ok sure, let me test out your awk command to understand it better and make any suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following awk command and let me know if this helps you. Will add non-one liner form of it too shortly.

```
awk -F, '{s=$4 " " $5; gsub(/[:-]/, " ", s); t=mktime(s); dt=strftime("%c", t); a[t]=dt; b[t]+=$6} END{for(i in a) print a[i] " has " b[i] " seconds"}'  Input_file
```

Thanks to Anubhava for correcting my code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your solution also works, But I chose @anubhava answer because it is shorter.

Comment: You can change your code to this: `awk -F, '{s=$4 " " $5; gsub(/[:-]/, " ", s); t=mktime(s); dt=strftime("%c", t); a[t]=dt; b[t]+=$6} END{for(i in a) print a[i] " has " b[i] " seconds"}' file`

Comment: @anubhava, thanks a TON for helping here. I have changed it now.